# Tensorflow object detection API classification loss increases

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I'm training tensorflow object detection API with my own data. The model I'm using is `ssd_mobilenet_v1` with pretrained coco checkpoint.
My dataset consist of 12 classes and each class has 110 images so total 1320 of them.
This works fine, but classification loss increases at some point.
[image]

I think insufficient of dataset doesn't matter in training phase because they are all similar; actually I extracted them from video.

So what should do? Should I stop training around 10k iteration? or is there any possible parameter tuning or data augmentation?

This is my config file which I just adjusted directories and `data_augmentation_option` and `hard_example_miner`.

```
model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 12
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      ssd_anchor_generator {
        num_layers: 6
        min_scale: 0.2
        max_scale: 0.95
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        aspect_ratios: 3.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.3333
      }
    }
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 320
        width: 180
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      convolutional_box_predictor {
        min_depth: 0
        max_depth: 0
        num_layers_before_predictor: 0
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 0.8
        kernel_size: 1
        box_code_size: 4
        apply_sigmoid_to_scores: false
        conv_hyperparams {
          activation: RELU_6,
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.00004
            }
          }
          initializer {
            truncated_normal_initializer {
              stddev: 0.03
              mean: 0.0
            }
          }
          batch_norm {
            train: true,
            scale: true,
            center: true,
            decay: 0.9997,
            epsilon: 0.001,
          }
        }
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'ssd_mobilenet_v1'
      min_depth: 16
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      conv_hyperparams {
        activation: RELU_6,
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 0.00004
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            stddev: 0.03
            mean: 0.0
          }
        }
        batch_norm {
          train: true,
          scale: true,
          center: true,
          decay: 0.9997,
          epsilon: 0.001,
        }
      }
    }
    loss {
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid {
        }
      }
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      hard_example_miner {
        num_hard_examples: 600
        iou_threshold: 0.99
        loss_type: CLASSIFICATION
        max_negatives_per_positive: 3
        min_negatives_per_image: 0
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 1e-8
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 96
  optimizer {
    rms_prop_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        exponential_decay_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.004
          decay_steps: 800720
          decay_factor: 0.95
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
      decay: 0.9
      epsilon: 1.0
    }
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "/home/dev1/tensorflow/training/data/checkpoint/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28/model.ckpt"
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type:  "detection"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
  num_steps: 100000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    ssd_random_crop {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_adjust_brightness {
    }
  }
}

train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/home/dev1/tensorflow/training/data/train.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "/home/dev1/tensorflow/training/data/config/label.pbtxt"
}

eval_config: {
  num_examples: 132
  max_evals: 20
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/home/dev1/tensorflow/training/data/test.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "/home/dev1/tensorflow/training/data/config/label.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
```

Comment: Maybe your learning rate is high, please change `decay_steps` to 5000 to reduce learning rate at 5000 step

Comment: @ShayanTabatabaee That works! Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing the solution here (Answer Section) even though it is present in the Comment Section (Thanks to Shayan Tabatabaee), for the benefit of the community.

This issue was due to high learning rate and it was fixed by decreasing `decay_steps` from `800720` to `5000`.

Please refer modified config file in below

```
model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 12
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      ssd_anchor_generator {
        num_layers: 6
        min_scale: 0.2
        max_scale: 0.95
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        aspect_ratios: 3.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.3333
      }
    }
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 320
        width: 180
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      convolutional_box_predictor {
        min_depth: 0
        max_depth: 0
        num_layers_before_predictor: 0
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 0.8
        kernel_size: 1
        box_code_size: 4
        apply_sigmoid_to_scores: false
        conv_hyperparams {
          activation: RELU_6,
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.00004
            }
          }
          initializer {
            truncated_normal_initializer {
              stddev: 0.03
              mean: 0.0
            }
          }
          batch_norm {
            train: true,
            scale: true,
            center: true,
            decay: 0.9997,
            epsilon: 0.001,
          }
        }
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'ssd_mobilenet_v1'
      min_depth: 16
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      conv_hyperparams {
        activation: RELU_6,
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 0.00004
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            stddev: 0.03
            mean: 0.0
          }
        }
        batch_norm {
          train: true,
          scale: true,
          center: true,
          decay: 0.9997,
          epsilon: 0.001,
        }
      }
    }
    loss {
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid {
        }
      }
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      hard_example_miner {
        num_hard_examples: 600
        iou_threshold: 0.99
        loss_type: CLASSIFICATION
        max_negatives_per_positive: 3
        min_negatives_per_image: 0
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 1e-8
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 96
  optimizer {
    rms_prop_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        exponential_decay_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.004
          decay_steps: 5000
          decay_factor: 0.95
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
      decay: 0.9
      epsilon: 1.0
    }
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "/home/dev1/tensorflow/training/data/checkpoint/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28/model.ckpt"
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type:  "detection"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
  num_steps: 100000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    ssd_random_crop {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_adjust_brightness {
    }
  }
}

train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/home/dev1/tensorflow/training/data/train.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "/home/dev1/tensorflow/training/data/config/label.pbtxt"
}

eval_config: {
  num_examples: 132
  max_evals: 20
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/home/dev1/tensorflow/training/data/test.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "/home/dev1/tensorflow/training/data/config/label.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
```

Comment: min_negatives_per_image: 0 ? How do we come up with the numbers? in the default config its 3